# SQL server 2005 installation SP1

Tags: sql

I have got problem with installation SP1 and SP2 to SQL server 2005 I get this text -> Instances of SQL Server Express cannot be updated by using this Service Pack installer. To update instances of SQL Server Express, use the SQL Server Express Service Pack installer.

I don't understand what I have to do?

I can`t select this box with SQL server 2005 to make update.

[image]

Start -> Menu

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running SQL Server Express, not the full version of SQL Server. SQL Server Express is the trimmed-down, free version of SQL Server.

You need to download the correct service pack installers (I suspect that you'd only need to install the latest one - SP4 - but I have no way of checking):

[SQL Server 2005 Express SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7478)

[SQL Server 2005 Express SP2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22625)

[SQL Server 2005 Express SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15291)

[SQL Server 2005 Express SP4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=184)